# How to refer to an class element in map::find() function?

Tags: c++, oop, stl

I want to create a simple data storage using map,

```
map<int , Person> people;
```

where Person is

```
class Person
{
    string name;
    int age;
public:
    Person() : name("noname"), age(0) {}
    Person(string name, int age) : name(name), age(age) {}

    void print()
    {
        cout << "| " << name << " | " << age << endl;
    }
};
```

and I have a problem with referring to people.name in map::find() function. Probably I just don't know the correct syntax and I can't find the answer. It probably should look something like that, but *name* is the element of *Person* class so I guess it should give me an error.

```
if (people.find(name) != people.end())
    {
        people.erase(name);
        cout << name << " removed from data base" << endl;
    }
else
    {
        cout << name << " not found" << endl;
    }
```

Sorry for my ignorance, but I started programming quite recently, that's why i don't know basic syntax and get confused sometimes.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. For instance, where are you calling `find` from? Do you get an error? If so, copy-paste it into the question. Do you expect one, but not get it, explain why do you expect it to be an error.

Comment: Please have a look at this [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) list.

Comment: It's possible that `std::map` is not the data structure you're looking for.

Comment: Did you think what would happen if you have more than one person with the same name ?

Comment: @KillzoneKid thanks for pointing that. I wanted to connect the key value with some id number of particular person, in that case _erase_ condition would have to make sure which person is to remove.

Comment: @J.Doe If you do not need frequent lookups by name, you can use `std::find_if` with custom comparator function to search map values. Otherwise you might want to rethink your design to fit your needs better.

Comment: @KillzoneKid Actually i think the problem is to access the `name` by a map. Is it executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have designed your map wrongly. If you want to use a name to look up a person then the name must be the key of the map, i.e.

```
map<string, Person>
```

where the string is the name.

Comment: I want to use _int_ key value to assign an id to a person. I create person like that: `people[0] = Person("Mike", 40);`, and in some point I want to erase this person with `map::erase` by finding a name. Is it possible to stay with _int_ key type, and still look for a name?

Comment: @Zezwul You could just loop through all the entries in the map until you find the one you want to delete (but note there is nothing in your design to make the name unique). Alternatively you need a more complex data structure. How about a second map from name to ID? Use the name to look up the ID and then the ID to delete from the first map.

Comment: I think i am stil missing something out. I thought that ID (key value) could make the name individual, because every person from `people` (`Person` class instance) has its unique _int_ value assigned.

Comment: `people[0] = Person("Mike", 40); people[1] = Person("Mike", 40);`. The IDs are different but the name is the same? Maybe we're talking about different things.

Comment: I wanted to connect the key value with some ID number of particular person, in that case _erase_ condition would have to make sure which person is to remove, so when there is a conflict involving two or more same names, ID would be essential to decide which. Like i said, i am a beginner so sometimes i am confused.

Comment: @Zezwul I think we're both saying the same thing. But having made the int ID the key to your map you need to do a bit of extra work to delete from the map using a name. Either of my two suggestions from the previous comment would work.

Comment: Yes, I've been trying to iterate through all the entries, but honestly i have no idea how. I tried this 
   `for(map<int, Person>::iterator it = people.begin(); it != people.end(); it++)
   {
    if (people.find(name) != people.end())
    {
     cout << "Found " << name << endl;
    }
    else
    {
     cout << name << " not found" << endl;
    }
   }`
but with no effect. Of course `name` was defined earlier.

Comment: `for(auto it = people.begin(); it != people.end(); it++) { if (it->second.name == name) { cout << "Found " << name << endl; } else { cout << name << " not found" << endl; } }` `auto` simplifies complex data types (what you wrote wasn't wrong however). When you have an iterator you don't need to use find, the iterator points at the data you want. In this case `it->second` is the `Person`. But you still have a problem because `name` is private in your `Person` class.

Comment: Yes, i remembered about privacy. Is there any way to workaround it?

Comment: Just add a getter to your class.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a `std::map<string, Person>` instead if you want to have a dictionary of `name` with the corresponding object?

In that case you can do:

```
auto person = nameToPersonDictionary.find(personName); 
if (person != nameToPersonDictionary.end()){
    nameToPersonDictionary.erase(personName);
    // person is a reference to object Person 
}else{ // Not found
}
```

If all you want to do is to build a lookup table you can consider [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). Another use case if the `name` is immutable property of the object `Person` (ie `name` is never modified for a person) `set` fits better.

You will have to provide an overload of `<` operator for set to work.

A simple example to provide the overload would be:

```
// This assumes that there are can't be two distinct person with same name
bool operator<(const Person &left, const Person &right){
    return left.name < right.name;  
}
```

Then you can directly query using an instance of `Person` object.